# Create centralised email service with flag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, feature-flags

I need to create a centralized email service with feature flag in .net . I have not used this before so I am not sure what's the best way to do it.
I need to Sort dev/test emailing to email logging in user as an over-ride, (Example: emails to your line manager, go to yourself on test.)
I need to move email into it's own service to use a feature flag based on the configuration to send all to the user.
Can anyone guide me please. Do I need to create a new project or add pages to the current project

Comment: Too many requirement. I would suggest you to list down all your requirements clearly. also you need to provide little bit background of your existing project . did you already tried something ?

Comment: @Nitz Thanks for your reply! I tried to add a project to the existing solution by following the microsoft doc for feature management. But I am not sure how do I create a centralized email service. Basically I want to sort out the emails for different environments (dev/Test) where in Test, Leave request email (Example) should go to myself instead of manager. If you could guide me on how to create an email service by using feature flag, that would be helpful

Comment: why do you need feature management here ?

Comment: @Nitz By using feature management I thought of sorting out sending emails to different users in dev/test. To create a service, I was given this reference- "https://mentormate.com/blog/service-and-repository-layer-interaction-in-c/". Can you guide me on this